# Power series of ln(x) within IOC requiring massive n?

Tags: calculus, power-series

So I am currently programming my own calculator in C. I am using power series to calculate the answers to keep my math sharp over the summer. However, in order to calculate something like ln(4.5) I need to use log rules to break it up to ln(2)+ln(2)+ln(.5). In trying to find natural log of 2, I had to use n=1000 to just get accurate to 2 decimal places (.69). I was hoping someone could give me pointers on how to reduce n and still get an accurate answer. I am running it on an Arduino that doesn't really have enough power to do that many computations. Here is my code if it helps:

```
double power(double n, double x) //(raised to, this number)
{
  if (n == 1)
  {
    return x;
  }
  else
  {
    return x*power(n-1,x);
  }
}

double lnX(double x)
{
  double result = 0;

  x = x-1;
  int n = 2000;

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    result += (power((i+1),-1))*power(i,x)/i;
  }

  return result;
}


int main()
{
float ln;
printf("Please enter a number: \n");
scanf("%f", &ln);
double answer = lnX(ln);
printf("ln of that number is equal to: %f \n", answer);
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia says that series for $\ln x = 2\,\text{arctanh} \frac{x-1}{x+1}$ converges more quickly and is used especially for $x$ close to $1$.  Many of the familiar Taylor series converge quite slowly and various tricks and optimizations are required to obtain reasonable performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious improvement is to use that $\log{2}=-\log{0.5}$, which converges rather more rapidly. One can further improve convergence by various other tricks, but you do have another problem: $\log{4.5} \neq \log{2}+\log{2}+\log{.5} $: the logarithm turns multiplication into addition, not addition into addition. You have instead $\log{4.5} = \log{3}+\log{1.5} = \log{2}+2\log{1.5} = -\log{0.5}+2\log{1.5}$.